# Customize WAR deployment for Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I'm using the Spring Framework (Spring Boot) with Maven. I'm making .war deployed (manually) on Tomcat 8.5. My application is sold to multiple customers.

I have 2 config files. The main application.yml which contains options common to all installations, and a application-custom.yml unique per installation (database credentials, mail etc.). This custom config file must not be erased when I update my war package (Tomcat erases the config file and replaces it by the newest of the war). But I don't want the custom file replaced by a new at every update.

To fix it, my Spring config file is actually (manually) copied in the webapps path of Tomcat (not erased when update like that) :

> C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\application-custom.yml

But this is not the best solution I guess. Because at every new install, I must create the custom config file by myself. Is there a better solution ?

Comment: You should better describe the actual problem you face instead of asking how you may implement a specific solution. Why do you need to copy custom.yml to application.yml in the first place? Explanation of "why" could surprise you with the readily available alternative solutions.

Comment: Maybe you can use different config files - one config file for dev and one config file for production? Like Vilmantas write: why you copy the config file into a different folder?

Comment: Thanks, I changed my topic. The secondary config file is customer specific. So it needs to be the same even after war update (because Tomcat replaces it by the one from the war when I update the war file).

Answer (score 0):

On every start you can move config file to safe place like for example `/webapps/configs` and after Tomcat extracts .war file move your config back.
To do this you need to modify `catalina.sh` in bin folder. After this line:

```
elif [ "$1" = "start" ] ; then
```

add this to move your config to safe place

```
cp $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/myApp/WEB-INF/classes/your_config.yml $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/configs
```

After this:

```
  if [ ! -z "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
    echo $! > "$CATALINA_PID"
  fi

  echo "Tomcat started."
```

add below to move your config back to the place :

```
cp $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/configs/your_config.yml $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/myApp/WEB-INF/classes
```

After that start your Tomcat using `catalina.sh start`

Comment: Thanks, but actually I want to avoid going into deployed war folder to copy paste the file, so if I need to modify Tomcat for every new installation, I lose more time. Can`t I do like you said, but directly inside the war package ?

Comment: You want to put your current config into war file? I don't understand why would you lose more time with this way? You do this one time and as I understand you copy paste config file every rebuild?

Comment: I'm not the one who is installing the app, we have a dedicated service to do this. So I would like the installation to be the easiest as possible.